# Cannot upload snupkg to artifactory, using nuget push

Tags: nuget, push, artifactory, nuget-package

I am trying to upload my *.snupkg file to artifactory.
Manually, this works through the website, but when I try to push with `nuget push` it doesn't work and also doesn't give any response

```
nuget push "*.snupkg" -Source "https://artifactory.test.be/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/nuget/symbol" -ApiKey "USR:key" -SkipDuplicate
```

Also I tried pushing the normal nupkg file, hoping that it will also upload the snupkg together, [like writter here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg), but also no success...

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the stupidity of the NuGet CLI to identify a v3 URL by ending on index.json. But that will not work with artifactory.

Use a NuGet.config, put the URL in there with protocolVersion="3" and then reference it by the Name Key you have given it and it will work.

By the way, if .nupkg and .snupkg are in the same folder, the .snupkg will be pushed automatically along the .nupkg file.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled for many hours with nuget push / dotnet push. I configured everything as described in the 'set me up' section of the package source within artifactory. At least I tried out the [jfrog cli](https://jfrog.com/de/getcli/) tool, which was super easy to set up. Using a source glob like `*.*nupkg` for the `jf rt u` command, packages and symbol packages are easily deployed.

Answer (score -1):

Artifactory added symbol server only starting from version 7.36.
According to the documentation the supported PDF formats are:

- Microsoft PDB V7 (Microsoft C/C++ MSF 7.00)
- Portable PDB v1.0

If your Artifactory version is older than that, you will need to upgrade your Artifactory version.
If you have version 7.36 or above, you should be able to configure Artifactory as a symbol server using the following guide:
[Artifactory as Your Symbol Server](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+as+Your+Symbol+Server)

Comment: So we have version 7.38. And uploading .snupkg packages manual trough the website interface works perfectly. It is only the nuget push through command line that doesn't work for .snupkg packages

Comment: And have you also setup Symbol configuration?

Comment: Is that a seperate configuration? I can upload symbol files to standard nuget configuration so I think that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a separate configuration for setting up artifactory as nuget symbol server